# C regexec returning false positives

Tags: c, regex

I am implementing a "bank" software and I have to take in an acceptable username, pin, and balance when creating a new user.

```
BANK: create-user bob 1234 11111
```

would be an example of a correct input

```
BANK: create-user bob0101 1234 11111
```

would be incorrect, basically a single word username, a 4 digit pin, and some integer.

regexec returns 0 for both username inputs even though it absolutely shouldn't.

the code is currently

```
regex_t regex_s, regex_i, regex_p;
int reti_s = regcomp(&regex_s, "[a-z A-Z]+", REG_EXTENDED);
.
.
.
reti_s = regexec(&regex_s, cmd[1], 0, NULL, 0);
```

where cmd[1] is the username

I don't have a lot of experience with C regex but I know this shouldn't allow numbers, any help would be great thanks!

Comment: If you want the username to contain only letters, and `cmd[1]` is the full username and only the username, then maybe you just need to use `^` and `$` anchors?

Comment: Thanks so much it's working in most cases now!

Comment: why is the second example incorrect?  you don't explain why.  Isn't `bob0101` a single word name?  cannot it have digits?  PLEASE EXPLAIN.

Comment: Your sample regexp allows spaces in a name.... this will make `"bob  "` valid!

Comment: Yes bob can’t have any numbers in it, that’s why the regex is just [a-z A-Z]+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match letters-only characters, you have to use something like this:

int reti_s = regcomp(&regex_s, "[a-z]+", REG_EXTENDED|REG_ICASE);

I added the REG_ICASE flag according to https://linux.die.net/man/3/regcomp.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: I don't see also the need of `REG_ICASE` or `REG_EXTENDED` flags.  Why use extended regular expressions if you are not using grouping at all?

Comment: I use REG_EXTENDED for completeness, because is the preferred syntax along other languages. REG_ICASE will match things like Bob which perfectly could be a valid username.

Answer (score 0):

`regexec` just returns `0` if the regexp simply matches.  If you want to extract information, you need to use an array of `regmatch_t` to store the matching of subexpressions.  Or if you are only interested in global matches, one array of just one `regmatch_t` element (to get the info about the match).

As the manual page says:

> The 0th member of the pmatch array is filled in to indicate what substring of string was matched by the entire RE.

and you have to use the `rm_so` and `rm_eo` fields of `regmatch_t` to get the initial position and the end position of the matched part of the string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I didn’t want to store matches though I just needed to check if a single word matches the format it needs to be. For example the pin value must be a 4 digit number. It’s been fixed now thanks to CertainPerformance